# Unknown error occuring when Unity tries getting a non-existent document from Firestore

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, error-handling, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently using Unity 2019.3.1. I'm trying to check whether a document already exists and create it if it doesn't. This is the function I'm currently using to do that:

```
// Used to check if a document exists
// database data type = FirebaseFirestore
// docRef = database.Collection("Data").Document(documentName)
public Task GetSpecificUserDocumentAsync(DocumentReference docRef)
{
    Debug.Log("Getting user document");
    return docRef.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

        if (snapshot.Exists)
        {
            OnFireStoreResult.Invoke();
            Debug.Log(String.Format("Document data for {0} document:", snapshot.Id));
        }
        else Debug.Log(String.Format("Document {0} does not exist!", snapshot.Id));
    });
}
```

The problem I'm currently facing now is that task.Result returns `"Not Yet Computed"` and also shows this error: `"System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Firebase.FirebaseException: Failed to get document because the client is offline."`

However, I can still connect to Firebase and retrieve data from Firestore. This also occurs when I'm trying to get a variable that doesn't exist. Are there any things I need to check for or are there any other methods to check for a document's / variable's existence?

Comment: In case of doubt you could always wrap this in `try-catch`. Also could you add the type of `database`?

Comment: Also I came across this `By default, GetSnapshotAsync attempts to provide up-to-date data when possible by waiting for data from the server, but it may return cached data or fail if you are offline and the server cannot be reached.` .. since the error even states that ... are you sure you are not offline?

Comment: @derHugo I used FirebaseFirestore. I'll try to use try-catch. And no I can still receive data from the server.

Comment: Well are you sure or is it just re-using cached data you received before?

Comment: @derHugo Sorry i think it actually is just re-using cached data. Is there a way to check if the server is offline?